# Rotate feature during map rotation in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a vector layer with features that have a rotation attribute.  I am using the rotation attribute to define the direction of the feature icon in the Style property as follows:

```
var style_outer = new ol.style.Style({
 image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
     anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
     anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
     anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
     src: './images/Feature_icons/Logo_Arrow_07.png',
     rotation: rotation,
     scale: photo_icon_resolution_function()
   }))
});
```

Where the rotation is defined based on the attribute + the map rotation angle, looks like this:

```
var map_rotation = map.getView().getRotation();
var rotation = feature.get(bearing) + map_rotation;
```

When the user rotates the map, the icon doesn't rotate to match in real time.  It only snaps to the correct angle when the user moves the map or interacts with the map after the rotation.  This makes sense as the style function is called only when these things happen.

My question is then, how can I rotate the icons at the same time that the user rotates the map?

I have tried catching the rotation event as follows:

```
map.getView().on('propertychange', function(e) 
    {
       loaded_layers[p].getSource().forEachFeature(function(feature){
       feature.setStyle(Photo_Style(feature));
       feature.changed();  //This is an alternative which also works
    });

});
```

This works in that it fires during rotation, but it still doesn't update the icons during the rotation process, only after the user stops rotating (which is certainly an improvement on having to make the user pan the map to get the update, but still not what I'm looking for).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `rotateWithView: true` on `ol.style.Icon`.

Comment: I wish I knew that 2 hours ago ;)